# Product filtering in Sequelize using Node JS

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to filter my search using three attributes 'location','department' and 'ctc_offered'. Currently, my code takes location as input and displays accordingly. How do I write the code where I am taking filter option for either of the three attributes and displaying accordingly?

```
const bycrypt=require('bcryptjs');
```

const db =require('../../models')
const Company = db.company

const coDisplay=async(req,res)=>{

```
    Company.findAll({
        where:{
            location:req.body.location
        }
    }) 
    .then((company) => {
      if (!company) {
        return res.status(400).send({ 
          status:"102", 
          message: "company Not found." });
      }
      res.status(200).send({
        status:"VB100",
        company: company});
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
    });


};

module.exports={coDisplay};
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the Sequelize operators accordingly to the documentation: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html.

Example below.

```
const { Op } = require("sequelize");
Post.findAll({
  where: {
    [Op.or]: [
      { authorId: 12 },
      { authorId: 13 }
    ]
  }
});
```